# Join Two Dataset In One SSRS Chart Report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i Have two data sets. First one dataset shows Total counts against each person and the Second one Dataset shows SLA breached counts against respective person. As before i used two charts for for the above datasets and result will be achieved but now i want these two datasets result in just one chart. kindly tell me how to do this to achieve desired result.
Dataset 1 (Total Counts query is):

```
Select Count(I.Id) AS TotalId,
U.Firstname AS Username
From I
Group U.Firstname
```

Dataset 2 (SLA Breached query is):

```
Select Count(I.Id) AS BreachedId,
U.Firstname AS Username
From I
***Where I.ResolvedDate > I. ResolvedByDate***
Group U.Firstname
```

The highlighted query is just used in dataset 2 which shows SLA Breached counts. Rest of the query in both dataset are same. so now i don`t know how show toghether. I used union all function but it add both TotalId and BreachedId.

Thanks

AhsanMisbah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want both aggregates to appear in the same query? if so change your select to

```
select  U.Firstname AS Username, Count(I.Id) AS TotalId, nullif(SUM(case when I.ResolvedDate > I. ResolvedByDate then 1 else 0 end ),0) as Breached
```

Comment: Wow thanks Jamie, it works. I thought today will gonna waste, you saved me. 
But it also show '0' against those persons whose incidents didn`t breached. There is no need of null values, i used ISNULL but no effect on it. Any idea how to resolve this too.

Comment: So those without breaches shows zero in the breaches column? what do you want it to show in that column?  obviously there will be a row for that username, as long as they have a record in the table. do you want null to appear where there are no breaches rather than 0?

Comment: Just show nothing for zero(0). Obivously there is a row for that user name i just need that Zero doestn`t appear.

Comment: I have edited my answer - it will show null where count of breaches is 0, when you use this in a datagrid it will show blank

Comment: Sorry, i edited my comment. Yippie it works. Thanks Jamie you are great.